# How do I remove a TabControl created in another event handler?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

So I'm making a program and I hit a wall, because I don't know how to pass a variable from one method to another. To explain the situation, I add the code:

1) I create a `toolStripMenuItem^ TestIsvalyti` on formload.

```
    private: System::Void Form2_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {      
            MenuStrip^ menu = gcnew MenuStrip;
            menu->Location = Point(0,0);
            menu->Size = System::Drawing::Size(this->Width, 25);

            ToolStripMenuItem^ ElDienynas = gcnew ToolStripMenuItem;
            ElDienynas->Text = "El. Dienynas";
            menu->Items->Add(ElDienynas);
            Controls->Add(menu);

            //TESTUI
            ToolStripMenuItem^ TestIsvalyti = gcnew ToolStripMenuItem;
            TestIsvalyti->Text = "ISVALYTI";
            menu->Items->Add(TestIsvalyti);
            TestIsvalyti->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form2::TestIsvalyti_Click);
            Controls->Add(menu);
            //TESTUI

         }
```

2) I have an event handler, which creates a `TabControl^ ElDienynasTab`

```
    private: System::Void menuGrupe_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
         {

             TabControl^ ElDienynasTab = gcnew TabControl;
             ElDienynasTab->Location = Point(14, 40);
             ElDienynasTab->Size = System::Drawing::Size(768, 500);
             Controls->Add(ElDienynasTab);

             TabPage^ LankomumasPazymiai = gcnew TabPage;
             LankomumasPazymiai->Text = "Lankomumas | Pazymiai";
             ElDienynasTab->Controls->Add(LankomumasPazymiai);

             TabPage^ namuDarbai = gcnew TabPage;
             namuDarbai->Text = "Namu darbai";
             ElDienynasTab->Controls->Add(namuDarbai);       
         }
```

3) I created another event handler for the TestIsvalyti MenuStripItem, which has to remove the ElDienynasTab from the 2) method, but I hit the wall there because I don't know how to pass the variable to this event handler.

```
             void TestIsvalyti_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
         {
              this->Controls->Remove(ElDienynasTab);
         }
```

Please explain to me how to do it and/or add a piece of code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different functions, `menuGrupe_Click` and `TestIsvalyti_Click`. Functions can't see local variables within other functions, so you need to increase the visibility of the `TabControl` if you really want to use that specific instance from another method.

Create a field in your form.

```
private: TabControl^ ElDienynasTab;
```

Store the TabControl in the field instead of a local variable.

```
this->ElDienynasTab = gcnew TabControl;
```

If you drag and drop components onto your form with the designer, you'll see that this is the pattern that's followed. In fact, unless there's some reason you need to dynamically create controls inside your `Form_Load` and `menuGrupe_Click` calls, you should be using the designer for all of this and not trying to write it yourself. It will put initialization code into `InitializeComponent()` and handle the creation of the appropriate fields for you.

Comment: Thank you, that helped.
But what If I need to create objects when I get info? 
For example: I send a query to database, I get ppl name, surname and the the number, hm ppl there is.? (And I only do this when I click the button)

Comment: @Rokas That's a pretty vague question. It really depends on how you're structuring your UI. If all of the data can be put inside an existing control, like a GridView, then you can just fill the control with data. If you need to dynamically create and add a completely new control for every piece of data, then you should probably at least consolidate the control creation logic into a separate function and just pass in the unique data that's needed. If you have a more specific question in mind, feel free to ask another question on Stack Overflow.